# Magento 2.4.2: How to add Canadian flag and a phrase in the footer?

Tags: magento2.3, template-override, footer-links

Somewhere in the footer we need a small Canada flag and the phrase "We ship to Canada". We are doing this because we decided to ship our products to Canada too besides within USA. Please share links to some Magento documentation explaining how template overriding is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override Footer.phtml or copyright.html in your theme and add your code/Text as per your need.

just copy below file and put in your theme. If you are using any theme then it may be already overrided by theme developer.

```
vendor\magento\module-theme\view\frontend\templates\html\footer.phtml

vendor\magento\module-theme\view\frontend\templates\html\copyright.phtml
```

mark as a solution if works for you :)

Comment: Will try this and accept it as answer if it works, thanks

Comment: ok. dont forget to clean cache after adding your code in phtml file.